# Java script code works only when I place it in the body section

Tags: javascript, html

I don't understand why this simple script works only when I place it in the body?

when i place the script within the head or in external JS file it doesn't work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First Web Page</h1>
<p>My First Paragraph</p>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 5 + 6;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the element you reference is defined only later (at the time the <head> is processed the browser hasn't processed the markup underneath it yet).

Comment: got it! thanks obe!!

Comment: np :) btw when you get an answer you should mark it as such (I noticed  that you posted several questions that have already been answered)

Comment: you mean adding a thanks comment?

Comment: nom there's this "V" thing you can click to mark an answer as the correct answer...

Comment: ן can't find it (:

Comment: it's right underneath the up and down arrows for increasing / decreasing an answer's score, to the left of the answer...